# Ember Js, Ember-Highcharts not updating changes to chartData

Tags: javascript, ember.js, highcharts, ember-cli

I'm using Ember-CLI and ember-highcharts to plot some data. The library works fine with test data but fails when I try to pull data from an API, so I believe that there might be some kind of race-condition going on. However, I can print the series from within my component just fine, so I'm uncertain why the highcharts component isn't listening for changes to chartData and updating accordingly.

Here's my assignment statement:

```
this.get('chartData')[0].data.setObjects(barItems);
```

And my charData element:

```
chartData: [{
    name: 'Temperature',
    type: 'column',
    color: '#8fb1e8',
    data: []
  },
  {
    name: 'Humidity %',
    type: 'line',
    color: '#393a3d',
    data: []
  }],
```

The template this is all being used in:

```
<p id="res"></p>
<div class="graph">
  {{high-charts chartOptions=chartOptions content=chartData}}
</div>
{{yield}}
```

The chart does populate with data after navigating away, and then back to the page. I also have a few jquery appends that disappear when the chart populates.

Any thoughts as to how to fix this, how to force components to load synchronously, etc. would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't use highcharts, but my guess is that it is looking for changes to the `content` variable, but not the properties of those items.  You may want to make all the items in your chartData variable contain Ember objects:

Comment: `chartData= chartData.map((d) => { return Ember.Object.create(d); });`

Comment: Just gave that a try. `objs[dataSet].data = arr;` `this.get('chartData').pushObject(Ember.Object.create(objs[dataSet]));` Where objs is one of the Humidity or Temperature objects from earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ember-highcharts` uses [`content.[]`](https://github.com/ahmadsoe/ember-highcharts/blob/a2157efcc33341967be79481fd14b35797636282/addon/components/high-charts.js#L30) as a dependent key meaning that it only updates if you change the length of your provided array. To workaround this you could use [notifyPropertyChange](https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange).

Comment: Thanks for the insight! While searching, I also came across [this tutorial](https://emberway.io/using-highcharts-js-in-an-ember-app-18a65d611644). Should be useful for anyone else who sees this thread.